# What does "his seal" mean in John 3:33?

Tags: john, word-study

> "Whoever receives his testimony sets his seal to this, that God is true." John 3:33 ESV. **"his seal."**

> "He who has received His testimony has testified that God is true." John 3:33 NKJB.

Often the "seal" is the Holy Spirit in the life of the Christian e.g:

2 Corinthians 1:22 **"sealed us".**

Ephesians 1:13 **"you were sealed".**

Ephesians 4:30 **"you were sealed".**

But not always: John 6:27 **"For on him the Father has set his seal".** I think here "him" is "the Son of Man".

Who is being sealed, by whom and by what in John 3:33?

My reading of Ellicott's and Pulpit commentaries on John 3:33, is that they don't agree about who is being sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does "his seal" mean in John 3:33?**

> Whoever receives his testimony sets his seal to this, that God is
> true." John 3:33 ESV.

**Whoever** - Any person.

**Receives His  Testimony** - Accepts Jesus teachings

Acts 17:11  NET

> 11 These Jews were more open-minded than those in Thessalonica,  for
> they eagerly received the message, examining the scriptures carefully
> every day to see if these things were so.

**Sets His Seal**- Has confirmed.[Figurately] that his teachings were true

**God is true**- Thal all prophecies  made by God are true [Romans 3:4]

Romans 3:4 NET

> 4 Absolutely not! Let God be proven true, and every human being[a]
> shown up as a liar,[b] just as it is written: “so that you will be
> justified[c] in your words and will prevail when you are judged.”[d]

Answer (score 1):

In John 3:33 the phrase “set to his seal” refers to the seals that government officials or noblemen would use to identify themselves. It is simply stating that those who receive the testimony of Jesus have identified themselves with God’s truth. The New American Standard translation reads, “has set his seal to this.” The Williams New Testament says, “has certified with a seal that God is true.” Beck’s American Translation says, “has stamped with his seal of approval that God tells the truth.”

In Corinthians, this “sealing” by God was mentioned by Paul in two other places in the New Testament (Ephesians 1:13 and 4:30).

“Sealing” in the Scriptures signifies security and protection (Esther 8:8, Daniel 6:17, and Ephesians 4:30), ownership (Jeremiah 32:11-12 and 2 Timothy 2:19), authentication of documents or finished transactions (Genesis 38:18, 41:42; and Jeremiah 32:9-10), and also is used figuratively and symbolically (Isaiah 8:16; Song Of Solomon 4:12, 8:6; Daniel 9:24; John 6:27; 1 Corinthians 9:2; Revelation 5:1-2, 5, and 9).

F.F. Bruce, in his commentary on Ephesians, gives us a good insight into Paul’s usage here when he states, “An owner seals his property with his signet to mark it as his; if at a later time he comes to claim it and his right to it is questioned, his seal is sufficient evidence and puts an end to such questioning.

So, the fact that believers are endowed with the Spirit is the token that they belong in a special sense to God...Other seals, literal or figurative (like circumcision, the seal of the covenant with Abraham), were affixed externally; the seal of the New Covenant is imprinted in the believing heart.”

Not only can we look at this sealing as a proof of ownership, but it is also a means of preservation. In the same way that people seal fruit in jars with airtight seals to make preserves, so our born-again spirits have been sealed with the Holy Spirit to prevent contamination from the flesh (Ephesians 1:13).

In Ephesians, the Greek word “SPHRAGIZO,” translated “sealed” here, means “to stamp (with a signet or private mark) for security or preservation” (Strong’s Concordance). The meaning clearly relates to the Holy Spirit protecting our salvation (Corinthians 1:22).

Answer (score 1):

The operative verb here is σφραγίζω (sphragizó) = I seal, or, I set a seal upon.  Apart from the book of Revelation, this verb occurs just seven times in the NT as follows:

- Matt 27:66 - So they went and secured the tomb by **sealing** the stone and posting the guard.
- John 3:33 - The one having received His testimony has **set his seal** that God is true.
- John 6:27 - Do not work for food that perishes, but for food that endures to eternal life, which the Son of Man will give you. For on Him God the Father has **placed His seal** of approval.”
- Rom 15:28 - Therefore having finished this, and having **sealed** this fruit to them, I will set off through you into Spain.
- 2 Cor 1:22 - the One also **having sealed** us and having given the pledge of the Spirit in our hearts.
- Eph 1:13 - in whom you also, having heard the word of truth, the gospel your of salvation, in whom also having believed you **were sealed** with the Holy Spirit of promise,
- Eph 4:30 - And do not grieve the Holy Spirit of God, in whom you **were sealed** for the day of redemption.

Summarizing the several meanings in BDAG, and from the above survey, σφραγίζω (sphragizó) was a means of security to certify that something was genuine and had not been tampered with between sender and receiver.  According to Paul, God';s seal is the Holy Spirit with which we are sealed  The aspect of this metaphor is two-fold

1. The Holy Spirit preserves us for the day of judgement/redemption (Eph 1:13, 4:30, Rom 15:28)
2. The Holy Spirit testifies that God is true so that we may have this absolute conviction (John 3:33, 16:13, 14, 2 Cor 1:22, etc.)

The above list could be extended if we include the cognate noun, σφραγίς (sphragis) = a seal or the mark made by a signet ring as proof of identification or ownership.

- 2 Tim 2:19 - Nevertheless, God’s firm foundation stands, bearing this **seal**: “The Lord knows those who are His,” and, “Everyone who calls on the name of the Lord must turn away from iniquity.”

Such is the miraculous work of the Holy Spirit on the lives of believers.

Comment: I write these things to you who believe in the name of the Son of God, **that you may know that you have eternal life**. - 1 John 5:13

Comment: @MikeBorden - Good point, agreed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A wax seal with a signet ring was how they signed documents certifying their authenticity.  It appears that this idea of certifying authenticity is the meaning here.

**Figure 1.** Senses of  in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software)
[image]

**Commentaries**

> Hath set his seal (ἐσφραγισεν [esphragisen]). First aorist active indicative of σφραγιζω [sphragizō] for which verb see Matt. 27:66. The metaphor of sealing is a common one for giving attestation as in 6:27. The one who accepts the witness of Jesus attests that Jesus speaks the message of God.
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Jn 3:33). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

> With reference to him who accepts the testimony of Christ it is stated that he attests that God is true. The simplest explanation is the following: those who accept Christ’s testimony concerning himself (namely, that he is the Son of God) thereby set the seal of their approval upon God’s own testimony regarding Jesus: “Thou art my beloved Son” (Luke 3:22; cf. John 1:34). They show that they believe that God is true in thus addressing Jesus. What is affirmed here in a positive way is stated negatively in 1 John 5:10, “He who does not believe God has made him a liar; because he has not believed in the testimony which God has borne concerning his Son.”
> --
> Hendriksen, W., & Kistemaker, S. J. (1953–2001). Exposition of the Gospel According to John (Vol. 1, pp. 149–150). Grand Rapids: Baker Book House.

> 3:33–34. As in 1:11–12, the negative generalization admits certain exceptions. By accepting Jesus’ testimony as to what he has seen and heard, the believer has certified that God is truthful—not just that Jesus is truthful, but that God is truthful. For (an important logical connective) the one whom God has sent speaks the words of God. Jesus so completely says and does all that God says and does, and only what God says and does (e.g. 5:19–30; 6:37–40; 8:29), that to believe Jesus is to believe God. Conversely, not to believe Jesus is to call God a liar (cf. 12:44–50; 1 Jn. 5:10).
> --
> Carson, D. A. (1991). The Gospel according to John (p. 213). Leicester, England; Grand Rapids, MI: Inter-Varsity Press; W.B. Eerdmans.

Answer (score 0):

> "And what He has seen and heard, that He testifies; and no one receives His testimony." John 3:32 NKJB

To understand **"his seal"** in John 3:33 I suggest we need to look at verses 32-34. When we see the context of **"his seal"** three issues come to my mind:

1. > "No man receives his testimony" V32. "He who has received his testimony". v33.

Only one ['whoever'-singular], Jesus, has received. [Most versions put "He who" not "whoever"]. Is that true or is "whoever" anybody?

2. In v33 NKJB has "He","His" and "God". In my mind that could be: Jesus has received the Father's testimony that the Father is true, as it was Jesus who saw and heard.
3. In John 6:27 "seal" is something between  the Father and the Son. If John uses "seal" consistently then again it might be the Father putting the seal of His Truth on the testimony of the Son e.g. "This is my beloved Son...". Matthew 3:17. [ Not the Holy Spirit's testimony in the life of the Christian which Paul refers to].

All of this leads me to this understanding:

v32. He/Jesus bears witness to what he has seen heard in Heaven. Yet no one receives his testimony. Man by himself can't believe; we need God's grace.

v33. Jesus' life is the testimony that the Father is true. Jesus' life has received the seal, i.e. the Father's seal, **"his seal"**when Jesus saw and heard the Father in heaven. Because of this Jesus' witness in this world is true.

Jesus has the Father's seal of Truth on his life-"This is my beloved Son...". Matthew 3:17.

v34. For he whom the Father sent, Jesus, speaks the words of the Father, for the Father gives the Spirit to Jesus without measure.

Conclusion: John consistently uses "seal" with a different emphasis than Paul in e.g. Ephesians.